# Submitting form to Servlet using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, servlets

I have an ajax script attached to an onclick event. When called, it's suppose to take
values from a form, submit it to a servlet, receive a response as JSON and then output
it in a div placed below this form.

However, when I click the button, I get nothing. No error, no output.

```
function ajax()
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
    xhr.open('GET', '/FormProcessor/?name='+name+'&gender='+gender,true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    //alert("before readystatechange");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
        {
            var json = document.getElementById("json");
            json.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
```

The HTML

```
<body>
        <form >
            <select name="name" id="name">
                <option value="REG_01">Mike</option>
                <option value="REG_02">Jane</option>
            </select> &nbsp;
            <select name="gender" id="gender">
                <option value="F0101">MALE</option>
                <option value="F0102">MALE</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" value="Get JSON" onclick="ajax()"/>
        </form>
        <div id="json">

        </div>
    </body>
```

If the url to my servlet is incorrect, shouldn't I get an error at least?

Comment: If you got an error, then `xhr.status` would never be `200` (which means OK). If the URL was wrong you would get `404` (Not Found).

Comment: What does your JavaScript console say? Does it show any messages?

Comment: What does your browser's developer tools' Net tab say? Does it show the request? Does it show the response? Do you get the data you expect and the HTTP status codes you expect?

Comment: Why are you setting a `Content-Type` header on the request? You are making a GET request, there is no content to describe the type of.

Comment: What are `document.getElementById("reg")` and `document.getElementById("const")` supposed to be? They don't match elements that appear in the HTML you've provided.

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake. They were suppose to be "name" and "gender" respectively.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. Fixed now.